# Switching first letter of two strings in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm doing some of the Google python exercises, this one on strings.

I've come across one where it asks to switch the first two letters of each of two strings.

So it has a function created called mix_up, and you basically have to create the definition. So basically I made two variables that hold each of the first two letters, and then I use the replace function, then add them together, and it should work. But instead I get the original strings added together, the letters are not switched.

```
def mix_up(a, b):
    first = a[0:2]
    second = b[0:2]
    a.replace(first, second)
    b.replace(second, first)
    phrase = a + " " + b
    return phrase
```

Comment: a, b = b[0:2]+a[2:], a[0:2]+b[2:]

Comment: You don't want to use `replace`, even with the answers below pointing out the error, because it will sub the first two letters anywhere they occur in the word. Use slicing as has been suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `replace` method returns a new string, rather than changing the original.

Try this instead:

```
a = a.replace(first, second)
b = b.replace(second, first)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `replace()` will replace *all* of the occurrences, not just the first, unless you specify otherwise. You can do this easily enough with something like:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
    new_a = b[0:2] + a[2:]
    new_b = a[0:2] + b[2:]
    phrase = new_a + " " + new_b
    return phrase
```

or more concisely:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
    return b[0:2] + a[2:] + " " + a[0:2] + b[2:]
```

You can also do `replace(first, second, 1)`, where that last argument is the maximum number of occurrences to replace.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` is not destructive, it creates a new object.

So reassign your values, e.g.: `a = a.replace(first, second)`