# how can I replace letters from each word and combine them together without function

Tags: python

I have this string

```
my_string = 'abc ' 'xyz'
```

I need to replace the first two letters of the first word with the first two letters of the last word
is it possible to do it without the mix.up function?

Comment: what is the `mix.up` function? what output do you currently get and expect?

Comment: the mix.up function apparently mix the letters but I don't want to use any function
I have the string
string = 'abc ' 'xyz'
I want it to be xyc abz

Comment: You have the string `abc xyz`. What literal(s) were used to create the string is irrelevant.

Comment: It looks as though you intentionally ignored the part of my comment about your current output, what issues are you actually having in doing this?

Comment: How each word is separated? Python interprets 'abc' 'xyz' as 'abcxyz'.  If it is separated like 'abc xyz' so you can split and swap in python.

Comment: it is separated like 'abc xyz'
how do I swap?

Comment: @Sayse i didnt mean to ignore it

the issue that I'm having is that I don't know how to swap the letters

basically this is what I need to do

Write a Python program to get a single string from two given strings, separated by a space and swap the first two characters of each string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching first letter of two strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473573/switching-first-letter-of-two-strings-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can you string slices like so:

```
my_string = 'abc ' 'xyz'
my_string = my_string.split()
output = my_string[1][:2] + my_string[0][2:] + " " + my_string[0][:2] + my_string[1][2:]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
xyc abz
```

If you want the string to have `'` in between the letters you can do:

```
output = my_string[1][:2] + my_string[0][2:] + "' '" + my_string[0][:2] + my_string[1][2:]
```

Output:

```
xyc' 'abz
```

OR

```
output = "'" + my_string[1][:2] + my_string[0][2:] + "' '" + my_string[0][:2] + my_string[1][2:] + "'"
```

Output:

```
'xyc' 'abz'
```

But I believe the first output is most useful.

You can do it without a function like so:

```
my_string = 'abc ' 'xyz'
output = my_string[4:6] + my_string[2:4] + my_string[:2] + my_string[-1:]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
xyc abz
```

If you have the strings separate before they are combinined you could do:

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'xyz'
output = s2[:2] + s1[2:] + " " + s1[:2] + s2[2:]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
xyc abz
```

Comment: thank you!
so i guess it still has to be with a function, correct?
.split is a function?

Comment: @DorElia you can do it without functions at all, but using a function is best.

Comment: just for the sake of it, how do I do it without the function?

Comment: @DorElia this works for any length of word. if you take the `split()` out and just swap `[0:2]` with `[4:6]` then it only works if the first word is 3 letters.

Comment: @DorElia I updated my answer with a non-function version.

Comment: what if the string size increases?

Comment: @ManishShetty as I mentioned in the comments only the 4th option does not account for string size changing. the other 4 options do take it into account.